Hwo to solve this DraggableScrollableSheet which touches the nav bar error
Here is the example of the same 
and here is my code snippet
class AccountScreen {
  void showAccountOptions(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
            expand: false,
            builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
              return CustomScrollView(
                controller: scrollController,
                slivers: [
                  SliverAppBar(
                    expandedHeight: 20,
                    floating: false,
                    pinned: false,
                    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                    centerTitle: true,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    title: Text('Account',
                        style: CustomTextStyle.heading(context)),
                    actions: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Done",
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                      [
                        // Profile Card
                        BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
                          builder: (context, state) {
                            if (state.user == null) {
                              return const Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              );
                            }
                            return EmailCard(
                              name: state.user!.fullName!,
                              email: state.user!.email!,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                        // Second Card
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5, 0, 5),
                          child: Text(
                            "MY TICKETS",
                            style: theme.textTheme.bodySmall,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Card(
                          elevation: 0,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              titlebuild(
                                  title: "Upcoming Events",
                                  iconData: Icons.event,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    _showUpcomingEvent(context);
                                  }),
                              const divider(),
                              titlebuild(
                                  title: "Past Events",
                                  iconData: Icons.history,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    _showEventHistory(context);
                                  }),
                              const divider(),
                              titlebuild(
                                  title: "Ticket History",
                                  iconData: Icons.receipt,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    _showTicketHistory(context);`your text`
                                  }),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),

                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5, 0, 5),
                          child: Text(
                            "MY COLLECTION",
                            style: theme.textTheme.bodySmall,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Card(
                          elevation: 0,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              titlebuild(
                                  title: "Liked Events",
                                  iconData: null,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    _showLikedEvents(context);
                                  }),
                              const divider(),
                              titlebuild(
                                  title: "Liked Venues",
                                  iconData: null,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    _showLikedVenues(context);
                                  }),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

Can anyone help me fix this ?
I have tried using SafeArea and padding but both of them did not work , I have tried using both padding and safe Area but both are not working also the flutter version is the latest one so there is no error there

How about the useSafeArea flag of showModalBottomSheet?
